# Two tables in two columns

Tags: tables

I have following problem:

I have two tables.....
Table one:

```
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{A} & \textbf{B} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Table two:

```
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{C} & \textbf{D} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

How can I make two columns for this `table` (on my page)? Like this:

```
there is some text....
TABLE ONE | TABLE TWO
there is some text...
```

Thank you for your advice.

Comment: Have you read of subcaption package and nested tabulars?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. As an aside, *really* consider not using so many lines and rules. Your data/ink ratio is suffering for it – it's visually cluttered.

Comment: Could not agree more with @SeanAllred; tables should have at most one `hline` separating column headings from the contents. Whitespace does a fine job of separating the information, it looks more attractive, and saves that precious toner cartridge

Answer (score 4):

You can put both the `tabular`s inside the same `table` environment:

```
\documentclass{Article}
\begin{document}
  Some text here Some text here Some text here Some text here Some text here Some text here
  \begin{table}[htb]
  \centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{A} & \textbf{B} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\quad
\vrule
\quad
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{C} & \textbf{D} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

Some more text to follow
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The page can be split into minipages, for the lazy:

```
some text...

\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{ c c }
...
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{ c c }
...
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}

some more text...
```